# How to lag return only previous month grouping from a set of date values?

Tags: google-bigquery

Hi I have a  a table as :

| date_key | month | customer_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-01-23 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-02-02 | 2 | 1 |
| 2022-02-15 | 2 | 1 |
| 2022-02-16 | 2 | 1 |
| 2022-02-18 | 2 | 1 |
| 2022-02-16 | 2 | 1 |
| 2022-05-18 | 5 | 1 |
| 2022-06-11 | 6 | 1 |
| 2022-06-12 | 6 | 1 |
| 2022-06-13 | 6 | 1 |
| 2022-06-15 | 6 | 1 |

and want to lag on last previous month above

| date_key | month | customer_id | lastMonth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 1 |  |
| 2022-01-23 | 1 | 1 |  |
| 2022-02-02 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-02-15 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-02-16 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-02-18 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-02-16 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-05-18 | 5 | 1 | 2 |
| 2022-06-11 | 6 | 1 | 5 |
| 2022-06-12 | 6 | 1 | 5 |
| 2022-06-13 | 6 | 1 | 5 |
| 2022-06-15 | 6 | 1 | 5 |

I tried using

```
select *
lag(month,1) over(partition by customer_id order by month) lastMonth
from table
```

However this does not seem to get the result as needed.
Please do help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```sql
SELECT *,
       LAST_VALUE(month) OVER (
         PARTITION BY customer_id 
             ORDER BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_key) * 12 + month 
             RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
       ) AS lastMonth
  FROM sample_table
 ORDER BY date_key;

Query results:

+-----+------------+-------+-------------+-----------+
| Row |  date_key  | month | customer_id | lastMonth |
+-----+------------+-------+-------------+-----------+
|   1 | 2022-01-01 |     1 |           1 | null      |
|   2 | 2022-01-23 |     1 |           1 | null      |
|   3 | 2022-02-02 |     2 |           1 | 1         |
|   4 | 2022-02-15 |     2 |           1 | 1         |
|   5 | 2022-02-16 |     2 |           1 | 1         |
|   6 | 2022-02-16 |     2 |           1 | 1         |
|   7 | 2022-02-18 |     2 |           1 | 1         |
|   8 | 2022-05-18 |     5 |           1 | 2         |
|   9 | 2022-06-11 |     6 |           1 | 5         |
|  10 | 2022-06-12 |     6 |           1 | 5         |
|  11 | 2022-06-13 |     6 |           1 | 5         |
|  12 | 2022-06-15 |     6 |           1 | 5         |
+-----+------------+-------+-------------+-----------+
```

Comment: this works but what if the month is 12 and 1? where there's a difference in year?
for example before 2021-12-01 and 2022-01-01. it returns null

Comment: You should use year information along with month like  **ORDER BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_key) * 12 + month**